# Wordpress W3 Total Cache CDN image issue (timthumb)

Tags: wordpress, cdn, timthumb

I have a wordpress webpage trendbasket.net that is using a theme called goodnews. I'm experiencing terrible load times and I'm trying to optimize the webpage, using a plugin called W3 Total Cache.

I recently signed up to a CDN network (rackspace) and I was hoping to use it to reduce the server load caused by the large image files. The theme I'm using has two options via it's settings you set either timthumb on or off.

The problem is when you set timthumb on it doesn't work with the CDN the code it generates is "http://0bd5ef55b96f0f7e0583-2ef896d8828e2bc0b67d5908a513e0bd.r93.cf1.rackcdn.com/en/wp-content/themes/goodnews47/framework/scripts/timthumb.php?src=http://www.trendbasket.net/en/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/dariosaric.jpg&h=340&w=615&zc=1" as you can see it still tries to use the image file uploaded in the root site and also I think my cdn doesn't support executing php files so timthumb is a deadend.

As far as I understand the theme is using another resizer called aqua resizer when you turn timthumb off. But the problem with that one is Wordpress doesn't upload the images created by this one to the CDN. Only the common  media files created by the wordpress is uploaded to the CDN ( 150x150, 300x300 and the original) but the theme is asking for 0bd5ef55b96f0f7e0583-2ef896d8828e2bc0b67d5908a513e0bd.r93.cf1.rackcdn.com/en/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/haberici_dwighthoward2-150x150-100x73.jpg which is not in the CDN server.

I need help to set up my CDN somehow, I'm ok with disabling both aqua resizer and timthumb or using any other plugin that you guys might suggest. Right now I'm lost and don't know what to change, so thanks for any help.

Comment: Also when I get a gtmetrix report on my webpage it says:
 "Specify image dimensions  F (0)
The following image(s) are missing width and/or height attributes."

So I guess overall the image resizing in this script is pretty bad, I think it might solve my problems if I can completely avoid using Aqua Resizer or Timthumb and use another plugin for the image resizing that will work well with the CDN..

Comment: I investigated the issue further. the code that wordpress use is something like:
        <?php $timthumb = of_get_option('timthumb');
      if ($timthumb == true) { ?>
                <img src="<?php echo MOM_SCRIPTS ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo mom_post_image(); ?>&amp;h=91&amp;w=126&amp;zc=1" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
  <?php } else { ?>
              <?php 
                                $thumb = mom_post_image(); 
                                $ntImage = aq_resize( $thumb, 126, 91, true );
                            ?>

Comment: this might help you http://wordpress-tips.info/timthumb-maxcdn-w3-total-cache-wp_get_attachment_image_src/2012/03/27/